# EWS SyncFolderItems for specific date range

Tags: exchangewebservices, php-ews

Is it possible to syncFolderItems for a calendar with EWS for a specific date range, like the current week?

If so, how (I'm using php-ews as a client)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the [Documentation for SyncFolderItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa580672(v=exchg.150).aspx) you'll see that there's no option available to select a date range. If you have a specific use case that you need to achieve, feel to post to the issues page of my `php-ews` library, [`garethp/php-ews`](https://github.com/Garethp/php-ews/issues) And I'll try to help you out